# error while comparing string in structs with entered strings

Tags: c, structure

I am entering valid name `Steve xyz @ //1` then also it is showing invalid name @ `//2`. I am unable to compare the name in structure and name inputted by user.

Comment: why did the code in the question disappeared?

Answer (score 1):

`fgets()` reads also the newline (`'\n'`) character at the end of the buffer (when possible). a newline is added when you press Enter at the console and it will make the comparison fails. from `man fgets`:

> Reading stops after an EOF or a newline. If a newline is read, it is stored  into  the  buffer. A terminating null byte ('\0') is stored after the last character in the buffer.

so the content of `empName` array for input "Steve xyz" will likely to be:

```
['S', 't', 'e', 'v', 'e', ' ', 'x', 'y', 'z', '\n', '\0', ...garbage]
```

here a rewrite of the code, basically you have to remove `'\n'` if it's there. there was also a problem in the initialization of the struct array:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct employee {
        int cardNo;
        char name[20];
        long salary;
        int age;
} emp[20] = {
        {0, "John Doe", 6500, 25},
        {1, "Steve xyz", 7000, 30},
        // initialize here other 18 structs if needed
};

int main(void)
{
        char empName[30];
        printf("Enter your name\n");

        char *ret = fgets(empName, 30, stdin);
        if (ret == NULL) {
                printf("Error while reading name\n");
                return 1;
        }

        // remove eventual trailing newline replacing it with '\0'
        empName[strcspn(empName, "\n")] = '\0';

        if (!(strcmp(empName,emp[1].name))) {      // 1
                // I don't know why you do this...
                strcpy(empName, "Steve xyz");
        } else {
                printf("Invalid name\n");          // 2
        }
}
```

**edit**: changed newline removal approach using `strcspn()` (thanks to @AndrewHenle in the comments) which seems to be a perfect fit for this task. from `man strcspn`:

> size_t strcspn(const char *s, const char *reject);
>
> calculates the length of the initial segment of s which consists entirely of bytes not in reject.
> returns the number of bytes in the initial segment of s which are not in the string reject.

Comment: [`empName[strcspn(empName, "\n")] = 0;`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28462221/4756299)

Comment: @AndrewHenle wow I didn't know about this function! this is a much cleaner solution, I think I'm going to edit the answer and use `strcspn()`

Answer (score 0):

fgets reads the characters from the input stream and also a newline character. So you need to remove the newline character from the empName and this can be done by:

```c
empName[strlen(empName) - 1] = '\0';
```

Comment: If `empName` is `""` (zero-length string) this invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't find any problem when empName is an empty string. Can you please re-confirm this?

Comment: IF `empName[0]` is `'\0'`, (zero-length string or `""`) `strlen(empName)` is `0` and the code tries to set `empName[ -1 ] = '\0'`.  That's undefined behavior.

Comment: Actually, If we input empty string then as a newline character will be added to it the last character will be '\n' so there won't be any problem right?

Comment: Not always.  `CTRL-Z` on Windows or `CTRL-D` can be used to close the terminal and send an string with no terminating linefeed.  There are probably other ways.  And if the line is long enough that it fills the buffer, it won't be terminated with a linefeed either.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct employee
{
    int cardNo;
    char name[20];
    long salary;
    int age;
} Employee;


int main()
{
    char empName[30];
    Employee emp[20];

    emp[1].age = 30;
    emp[1].salary = 7000;
    emp[1].cardNo = 1;
    strcpy(emp[1].name, "Steve xyz");
    
    int len = strlen(emp[1].name);
    emp[1].name[len] = '\n';

    printf("Enter your name\n");
    fgets(empName, 30, stdin);


    if (!(strcmp(empName, emp[1].name))) //1
    {
        strcpy(empName, "Steve xyz");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Invalid name\n"); //2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tha fact is `fgets()` is reading also the `\n` char, so you have to do this after using `fgets()`

```
   size_t len = strlen(empName);

    if (len > 0 && empName[len-1] == '\n') {
        empName[--len] = '\0';
    }
```

With this we delete the `\n`, and now the comparison will determinate that are equals